# How to interpret the T-depiction of multiple comparisons used in R's multcompView package?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

R's multcompView package offers a seemingly useful set of tools to visualize the results of multiple comparisons, e.g. Tukey HSD analysis, including boxplots and 'letters' to identify significantly-different groups. It also provides a "t" depiction, in which groups are labeled with either a box, a sort of pyramid, or nothing. For instance:

```
require(multcompView)
y <- c(0,1,0, 1,2,1, 2,3,2, 8,9,10)
df <- data.frame(l=gl(4,3), y=y)
multcompBoxplot(y~l, data=df)
```

I can't make any sense of these "t"s, and can't find a clear explanation of them in the literature or documentation. Can anyone explain them to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the package--

under a directory like: 
/home/USERID/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/multcompView/doc

you'll find this file:
VisualizingPairedComparisons.pdf

It's explained in there.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @MarkMcFarland. Would you mind giving an overview of the explanation listed there, eg, in case of linkrot, & to help future readers decide if it's something they want to pursue?